# Register user script not verifying password

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, slight issue with my user registration script, for some reason its not checking that form fields pass1 and pass2 are the same despite it being in the code, any ideas? I will put the register code in full below for your review. I am quite new to PHP so any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you for your help. :-)

The registration script.

```
<?php
ob_start(); // Start output buffering

function isLoggedIn()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'])
        return true;
    return false;
}


session_start();
//if the user has not logged in
if(!isLoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: ../index.php');

    die();
}


?>
<?php require_once('../Connections/PropSuite.php'); ?>

<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$colname_user = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  $colname_user = $_SESSION['username'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_Takeaway, $Takeaway);
$query_user = sprintf("SELECT type FROM admin_users WHERE username = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_user, "text"));
$user = mysql_query($query_user, $Takeaway) or die(mysql_error());
$row_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($user);
$totalRows_user = mysql_num_rows($user);






  // Username available.


//form begins
 $user_type = $row_user['type'];

    if ($user_type === 'admin-full') 
    {
//retrieve our data from POST
$name = $_POST['name'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
$pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];
if($pass1 != $pass2)
    header('Location: register-admin.php?pw=notmatched');
if(strlen($username) > 30)
    header('Location: register-admin.php?username=toolong');
if(strlen($name) > 40)
    header('Location: register-admin.php?name=toolong');

$hash = hash('sha256', $pass1);

//creates a 3 character sequence
function createSalt()
{
    $string = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    return substr($string, 0, 3);
}
$salt = createSalt();
$hash = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash);


mysql_select_db($database_Takeaway, $Takeaway);
//sanitize username
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);

$q = "SELECT id, username FROM admin_users WHERE username = '$username'";
$results = @mysql_query($q);
if(mysql_num_rows($results) > 0)
{
  // Username exists.
 header('Location: register-admin.php?username-taken');
}
else
{


$query = "INSERT INTO admin_users ( type, email, name, username, password, salt )
        VALUES ( 'admin-full', '$email', '$name', '$username' , '$hash' , '$salt' );";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
header('Location: ../main?NewUserAdded');
}

mysql_free_result($user);
    } 
    else {
?>
You are not authorised to do that!
<?php } ?>
```

UPDATE

The form code is

```
<form name="register" action="register-admin1.php" method="post">
     <?php if (isset($_REQUEST["username-taken"])) { ?>
        <p style="color: #F00">Username already exists! please try again</p>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if (isset($_REQUEST["pw=notmatched"])) { ?>
        <p style="color: #F00">Username already exists! please try again</p>
        <?php } ?>
     <p>Register New Admin User<br />
       (Note! Admin users are top level and will have access to everything!)
       <br />
     </p>
       <p>Name:
         <input name="name" type="text" id="name" maxlength="30" />
       </p>
       <p>Email:
         <input name="email" type="text" id="email" maxlength="30" />
       </p>
       <p>Username:
         <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" />
       </p>
       <p>
         Password:
           <input type="password" name="pass1" />
       </p>
       <p>Password Again:
         <input type="password" name="pass2" />
     </p>
       <p>
         <input type="submit" value="Register" />
       </p>
     </form>
```

Comment: That `GetSQLValueString` function is absolutely terrifying. What purpose does this serve other than to obfuscate your reckless disregard for [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `die();` after `header('Location: register-admin.php?pw=notmatched');` since the script will keep executing otherwise and set any other headers that you have.

Like so:

```
if($pass1 != $pass2) {
    header('Location: register-admin.php?pw=notmatched');
    die();
}
if(strlen($username) > 30) {
    header('Location: register-admin.php?username=toolong');
    die();
}
if(strlen($name) > 40) {
    header('Location: register-admin.php?name=toolong');
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are expecting the username value to be in session at the point where you are querying the database to get information on the user.  I don't understand how the username would be in session if you are just posting it a form.  Your conditional

```
if ($user_type === 'admin-full')
```

seems like it would never evaluate to true as you have not yet pulled the username out of the post array and evaluated it.

Note you should also use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql_*` functions as these are deprecated in PHP.

Comment: Hi there, yes this is for an admin user to add another admin user so I need to grant access to the page only to people with a full admin account